# How do I import a package in a simple Dart script (no pubspec.yaml)?

Tags: dart

Let's say I have a simple script such as this:

```
// File main.dart
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

main() {
  print(new Uuid().v1());
}
```

And I run it from command line via `dart main.dart`.

How do I make the `import` work? The error I got was:

```
Could not import "package:uuid/uuid.dart" from "file:///C:/folder/main.dart": 
Could not resolve a package location for base at file:///C:/folder/main.dart
```

I already did a `pub global activate uuid`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pubspec.yaml` and `pub get` (or `pub upgrade`) are used to make a package available to your project at all.
Only after a package is available libraries from this package can be imported using a package URI.

`pub global activate` is to make packages available that contain executables to be executed from the command line.

See also https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/get-started

Comment: So if I want to make just a simple script (not a package), I can't even use a pub package at all?

Comment: Packages are not a Dart feature, they are a `pub` feature. If you want to use `pub` features, you need to create your application as a pub package. You can use file imports without creating a `pub` package. Just use `import 'path/to/file.dart';`.